# Only remove jQuery slide transition from first instance of function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child, transition, slidedown

Alright, I'm using the UberMenu Plugin for Wordpress. When you click the parent item in a menu, the child-menu slides down into position underneath and stays put. After clicking on a child-menu link, the normal function is for the child-menu to disappear and be reactivated by click on the parent item again.

So, I wanted the child-menu to stay visible after going to a child-page and afterwards continue with the original functionality after that very first instance. Miraculously, I've gotten this far with success.

You can view the working menu/sub-menu here: http://goo.gl/MC8Aw

I added this code to the UberMenu.dev.js:

```
jQuery('document').ready( function($){
    var id = $( '#megaMenu ul.megaMenu > li.current-menu-item, #megaMenu ul.megaMenu > li.current-menu-parent, #megaMenu ul.megaMenu > li.current-menu-ancestor' ).live().first().attr( 'id' );
    uberMenu_openMega( '#' + id );
});
```

You can see the entire .js file here: http://goo.gl/xZd6g

Alright, so the only issue is that when the child-page loads and the child-menu is triggered immediately by the above code, it's retaining the slide transition from the primary functionality. This gives a delayed look/experience to the child-menu that I want to avoid/minimize.

Is it possible to amend the above code (which seems already set up to only affect the first appearance of the menu) so that it also ignores the slide transition needed throughout the rest of the plugin?

Comment: I didn't understand your question, I notice that when a submenu is loaded, you have to click two times in the parent menu to close the slider ... do you want avoid that too?